# Calculating Balances in Mysql and Carry Forward to Next Row

Tags: mysql

I have following MySQL table named CashFlow, they have monthly loan accounts details like Month ID, Loan Account No, Installment, Overdue Amount

```
FMONTH | ACTNO | INSTALLMENT | OVERDUE
--------------------------------------
1      |  1001 |  500        | 10000
2      |  1001 |  500        | 
3      |  1001 |  500        |
1      |  2001 |  1500       | 20000
2      |  2001 |  1500       | 
3      |  2001 |  1500       |
```

I want to display this list as follow

```
FMONTH | ACTNO | INSTALLMENT | OVERDUE
--------------------------------------
1      |  1001 |  500        | 10000
2      |  1001 |  500        | 9500
3      |  1001 |  500        | 9000
1      |  2001 |  1500       | 20000
2      |  2001 |  1500       | 18500
3      |  2001 |  1500       | 17000
```

I am trying lot of technique but unfortunately I am unable to complete this Job in MySQL

Please help me how to calculate overdue amount after deduction of Installment in next month as above format in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Start with this. On larger datasets, a solution using vars will be faster, but you would probably use the same subquery.

```
SELECT a.*
     , SUM(b.payments) balance
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.fmonth
            , x.actno
            , COALESCE(x.overdue,y.installment*-1) payments 
         FROM cashflow x 
         LEFT 
         JOIN cashflow y 
           ON y.actno = x.actno 
          AND y.fmonth = x.fmonth - 1
     ) a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT x.fmonth
            , x.actno
            , COALESCE(x.overdue,y.installment*-1) payments 
         FROM cashflow x 
         LEFT 
         JOIN cashflow y 
           ON y.actno = x.actno 
          AND y.fmonth = x.fmonth - 1
     ) b
    ON b.actno = a.actno
   AND b.fmonth <= a.fmonth
 GROUP 
    BY a.actno
     , a.fmonth;
```

Comment: Thanks for your very helpful answer. My issue is resolved. I am first time using stack overflow. I am highly appreciate  to you and this site owner.

Comment: Around here, appreciation is best demonstrated through 'up votes' and 'acceptance' ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
aggregate function -calculate overdue-installment

 group by   -account number
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.